# Can't retrieve valid online presence data from Facebook with proper privilege set and user being online

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm facing a trouble with some code that used to work before. I want to retrieve information whether user is currently online on Facebook's website chat. Thus, I'm requesting access token with 'user_online_presence' privilege and when running fql query:

```
"SELECT uid, name, pic_big, online_presence, status, current_location 
FROM user 
WHERE uid="+userId
```

(where userId is replaced by the real id of the user)

'online_presence' field is always 'offline' although I have my test account opened in the browser and test user is online for chat. All other information is presented correctly. And I know that this code used to work couple of months ago. I tried with several user account, but the same result always.

Is anyone facing similar issues? Has there been any API change I'm not aware of (I did search for the ones related to the online_presence field in 'user' table but without any success)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot, but have you tried using `WHERE id = me()` rather than feeding in the user id?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I want from my external application to catch when a user is online on facebook chat, not his friends

Comment: Apologies, I miss read your question.  It's surprising that it worked and now it does not.  I've suggested another answer, but I doubt it really makes any difference - worth a shot though :)